# How to push into arrays when reading ruby files?

Tags: ruby

I've followed the tutorial about how to read a text file with ruby with the purposes of printing it out with arrays, but it doesn't seem like working... here are the attempts in test.rb.

tutorial:https://www.codecademy.com/articles/writing-to-file-ruby

this test list file is successfully printing put in the console but its not in an array, how do I turn it into array? thanks!

```
# test.rb 
class File
  File.open("test_list.txt").each do  |line|
    puts line

    def ProcessText
      test_list.txt = File.to_s
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Why do you re-define the same method over and over again in the block? Especially since you never call it? Also, the method makes no sense. `File.to_s` is simply `"File"`, and `test_list` is undefined.

Comment: i know what you mean! i shouldnt name the class name as File as class name file has already been taken in ruby.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to save each line in an array. This is what you would do

```
# test.rb
class File
  array = []
  File.open("test_list.txt").each do  |line|
    array << line
    def ProcessText
      test_list.txt = File.to_s
    end
  end
  puts array
end
```

Comment: Why do you re-define the same method over and over again in the block? Especially since you never call it? Also, the method makes no sense. `File.to_s` is simply `"File"`, and `test_list` is undefined.

Comment: Don't ask me, I just added the array stuff. It can be refactored for sure but the question is not about refactoring.

Comment: @SgtPepper hi thank you so much for answering, i was wondering when i did  File.open.each do  |line| and it returns wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..3)